# Why RubyMine is not able to detect the following keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am using RubyMine for writing a Rails application and so far I really like it but I have couple of questions.

If you see the below image, I am trying to figure out why the RubyMine is not able to recognize `before_action` keyword. Even the keywords like `belongs_to` is not recognized.

I want to know why this is happening to this particular project? I am assuming the ruby path is not properly configured but I don't know where to set this?

Can anyone help me with this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: JFYI, those are not keywords. They are plain old method calls. Granted, rubymine should have recognized them as special rails methods. What is your ruby sdk set to on this project?

Comment: Ruby SDK - `rbenv 2.1.8`

Comment: I see those are underlined as errors. What is the error?

Comment: Those are not errors but RubyMine is not able to recognize it. It cannot find the definition of `before_action`.

Comment: I'd bet it's your ruby sdk setting. Configure a new sdk, by choosing the proper ruby binary and not some rbenv wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Sergio for the help. So the rubymine was using `rbenv 2.1.8` whereas the project is using the global ruby which is `2.2.3`. I reconfigured the SDK, and all issues are resolved. Thank you :)